# Is it possible to make a web app which can show details based on a number entered?

Tags: web, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I have a rudimentary knowledge of HTML and CSS I'm a non-coder.

I need to make an app (on a webpage) that can scan a QR code (which will contain a 12-digit number only)

and when this number is entered, (as a result of scanning or manually) it will show the details associated with that number.

I have all the details and numbers stored in a Google sheet.

Is it possible to make such an app? I'm ready to learn the necessary code and coding skills.

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell you that you can do it also with no experience,

 because nowadays with the help of some open-source libraries the job it will be a lot easier!

> with the help of their documentation it can be done.
>
>  the goal of the library is to make the work easier, by deleting complexity.

| functionality | name of library | link | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| generate QRcodes | `qrcode.js` | https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ | is the most simple library but is old, it can have some bugs, if you want a better library use the next one below |
| read Qrcode | `html5-qrcode` | https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode | super powerful with a lot of functionalities and it has amazing support until now, you can use the camera to get the QRcode / also gallery image and much more... but can be hard at the first try |
| read the spreadsheet and turn it to API JSON | `gsx2json` | https://gsx2json.com/ | JSON is the easiest format to get data from in JS... also for getting data you need to use the [`fetch(url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) web api |

> if you are stuck in every problem just search on google,
>
> for example: *"how to fetch some data from a URL in javascript?"*

hope this helps.

---

also if you want to learn the basics of javascript, you can use:

- w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/
- freecodecamp: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/
- ...much more